# Tail operation in directories that have similar files under

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, file-io, tail

I am looking for a smart way to handle this case.

Under `cpu-0` and `fhcount` directory, there are many files yet they can be grouped under some names.

Here is the bird's eye view of the directories and files.

```
../cpu-0/
        cpu-idle-01-01-2016
        cpu-idle-02-01-2016
        cpu-idle-03-01-2016
        .
        .
        cpu-interrupt-01-01-2016
        cpu-interrupt-02-01-2016
        cpu-interrupt-03-01-2016
        .
        .
        .
        cpu-nice-01-01-2016
        cpu-nice-02-01-2016
        .
        .
../fhcount/
        file_handles-max-01-01-2016
        file_handles-max-02-01-2016
        file_handles-max-03-01-2016
        .
        .
        file_handles-unused-01-01-2016
        file_handles-unused-02-01-2016
        file_handles-unused-03-01-2016
        .
        .
        .
        file_handles-used-01-01-2016
        file_handles-used-02-01-2016
        .
        .
```

As you can see, there is a pattern. I have collected them via hardcoding in order to `tail` the related files.

```
curdir="${PWD%}"

tail -q -n +2 $curdir/cpu-0/cpu-idle* > cpu-idle_combined
tail -q -n +2 $curdir/cpu-0/cpu-interrupt* > cpu-interrupt_combined
tail -q -n +2 $curdir/cpu-0/cpu-nice* > cpu-nice_combined

tail -q -n +2 $curdir/fhcount/file_handles-max* > file_handles-max_combined
tail -q -n +2 $curdir/fhcount/file_handles-unused-* > file_handles-unused_combined
tail -q -n +2 $curdir/fhcount/file_handles-used-* > file_handles-unused_combined
```

How could I do the same thing but this time smarter?

Comment: What is `"${PWD%}"` supposed to expand to? The expansion is removing the empty string from the end of `PWD`, i.e., doing nothing, isn't it?

Comment: It expands to the current directory where our script sits. e.g. home/scripts/
So, under home/scripts/ we have cpu-0/ and fhcount directory.

Comment: I meant, why are you using `%`?

Comment: You can discard that part yes.

Comment: And you're printing all files starting from their second line. How is the name of the output files determined? Can it be inferred from the input directories? Is it the input directory name up to the date part?

Comment: Yes, in order to skip the column names. Those are collectd outputs. Those name tags are stable since they are reported via collectd. Yet, I have shared couple for each, in reality there are more than 3-4 names for each component that's why it does not make sense via hardcoding it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This goes through all files in subdirectories, collects the common part of filenames, then prints them into the combined output files:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Required for the +(pattern) glob
shopt -s extglob

# Associative array used as set of unique file name roots
declare -A roots

# Shorten names like cpu-0/cpu-idle-01-01-2016 to cpu-0/cpu-idle
# +([[:digit:]-]) matches digits and hyphens
# ${fname%%pattern) removes the longest match of pattern from the end of fname
for fname in */*; do
    roots["${fname%%+([[:digit:]-])}"]=1
done

# Loop through unique roots, print to output files
for fname in "${!roots[@]}"; do
    tail -q -n +2 "$fname"* > "$fname"_combined
done
```

Associative arrays require Bash 4.0 or newer.

For an example input file structure of

```
.
├── cpu-0
│   ├── cpu-idle-01-01-2016
│   ├── cpu-idle-02-01-2016
│   ├── cpu-idle-03-01-2016
│   ├── cpu-interrupt-01-01-2016
│   ├── cpu-interrupt-02-01-2016
│   ├── cpu-interrupt-03-01-2016
│   ├── cpu-nice-01-01-2016
│   ├── cpu-nice-02-01-2016
│   └── cpu-nice-03-01-2016
└── fhcount
    ├── file_handles-max-01-01-2016
    ├── file_handles-max-02-01-2016
    ├── file_handles-max-03-01-2016
    ├── file_handles-unused-01-01-2016
    ├── file_handles-unused-02-01-2016
    ├── file_handles-unused-03-01-2016
    ├── file_handles-used-01-01-2016
    ├── file_handles-used-02-01-2016
    └── file_handles-used-03-01-2016
```

the resulting output structure is

```
.
├── cpu-0
│   ├── cpu-idle-01-01-2016
│   ├── cpu-idle-02-01-2016
│   ├── cpu-idle-03-01-2016
│   ├── cpu-idle_combined
│   ├── cpu-interrupt-01-01-2016
│   ├── cpu-interrupt-02-01-2016
│   ├── cpu-interrupt-03-01-2016
│   ├── cpu-interrupt_combined
│   ├── cpu-nice-01-01-2016
│   ├── cpu-nice-02-01-2016
│   ├── cpu-nice-03-01-2016
│   └── cpu-nice_combined
└── fhcount
    ├── file_handles-max-01-01-2016
    ├── file_handles-max-02-01-2016
    ├── file_handles-max-03-01-2016
    ├── file_handles-max_combined
    ├── file_handles-unused-01-01-2016
    ├── file_handles-unused-02-01-2016
    ├── file_handles-unused-03-01-2016
    ├── file_handles-unused_combined
    ├── file_handles-used-01-01-2016
    ├── file_handles-used-02-01-2016
    ├── file_handles-used-03-01-2016
    └── file_handles-used_combined
```

and for example input file contents like

```
$ head cpu-idle*
==> cpu-idle-01-01-2016 <==
1cpu-idle-01-01-2016
2cpu-idle-01-01-2016
3cpu-idle-01-01-2016

==> cpu-idle-02-01-2016 <==
1cpu-idle-02-01-2016
2cpu-idle-02-01-2016
3cpu-idle-02-01-2016

==> cpu-idle-03-01-2016 <==
1cpu-idle-03-01-2016
2cpu-idle-03-01-2016
3cpu-idle-03-01-2016
```

the combined output files contain

```
$ cat cpu-idle_combined
2cpu-idle-01-01-2016
3cpu-idle-01-01-2016
2cpu-idle-02-01-2016
3cpu-idle-02-01-2016
2cpu-idle-03-01-2016
3cpu-idle-03-01-2016
```

Comment: Thanks a TON! This helps quite a lot.

Comment: One question might be what if I have files like:
`file_handles-used_combined-1-01-01-2016`
`file_handles-used_combined-2-01-01-2016`
`file_handles-used_combined-3-02-01-2016`
`file_handles-used_combined-10-02-01-2016`

They are different I would not want to tail them. How can I refrain from such action. Since, the code gets rid of the digits, I believe that may cause a wrong behavior. How could we tackle that?

Comment: @Elesmoth What should the behaviour for these files be? They have the same name as the aggregate files, but with the suffix that we're removing from everywhere else?

Comment: I have made a mistake while giving the filenames. 
They should be cpu-idle-2016-01-01, memory-free-2016-10-02, irq-88-2017-02-03. irq's have problematic file names. Thus, we can split via "-201*". So, can we alter a workaround to your solution? Or, should I work for another way of doing this?

Comment: @Elesmoth You can replace `${fname%%+([[:digit:]-])}` by `${fname%%201*}` in that case. `shopt -s extglob` is no longer needed. Notice that this breaks for `irq-201-`, should you ever have that. If you know which years will appear, you can make it a little more stable, for example for 2016 and 2017: `${fname%%201[67]-*}` only matches `2016-` and `2017-`.

Comment: Well, you are right:) the latter option with [678] would definitely work for me. Again, thank you for your time!